# SharePoint List 'NoCrawl' with Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

The SharePoint API to GET a list, shows the boolean property 'NoCrawl' in its response. This property can be set by altering the settings for the Search availability and Offline access through the settings.

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')
```

However the Graph API counterpart doesn't have this property.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/
```

**Update** - Seems there is no way right now other than using the old SharePoint API itself. I'll keep the question open if in case the feature in inculcated.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such property called `NoCrawl` as of now in the [public document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-beta) and any relationship for expanding even in beta.

Comment: I remember a [related thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242605/sharepoint-online-rest-api-filter-by-boolean-yes-no) which works in SharePoint online rest api, which you may want to give a try with Microsoft Graph and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

As Shiva updated there is no such property called NoCrawl as of now in the [public documen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-beta)t and any relationship for expanding even in beta. Being said that I remember a [related thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242605/sharepoint-online-rest-api-filter-by-boolean-yes-no) which works in SharePoint online rest api, which you may want to give a try with Microsoft Graph and see if it helps your scenario.